# Error causing after deploy Reactjs project with mobx on heroku

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, heroku, mobx

Well, I've been working on this project for a while, and everything was fine and worked well until I deployed the project to heroku. (I use React and MobX as my state)

After I deployed the project to heroku, I pressed the link to see if everything is ok but every page that contains MobX is totally blank and this was in the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jr7c.png) (sorry, I can't upload images yet so please press the "console" link to see the screenshot.)

When i get back to dev to see if there's something wrong, or maybe I missed something. Everything is fine and everything's working so I have no idea what to do.

Here's my scripts:

```
"scripts": { 

 "start": "node scripts/start.js", 

 "build": "node scripts/build.js",

 "test": "node scripts/test.js", 

 "heroku-postbuild": "npm ci && npm run build" 

}
```

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: How are you building your application on Heroku? Do you have a `Procfile`? What are your `"scripts"`?

Comment: @Chris Hey man, what do you mean about 'Procfile'? and this's what I have on my scripts:  `"scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm ci && npm run build"
  }`

Comment: I mean exactly what I asked: Do you have a file called `Procfile` in the root directory of your project? This controls how Heroku runs your application. As to the scripts, please [edit] your question and add them there. It's very hard to read stuff like that in comments.

Comment: @Chris I don't have `Procfile`, its not my first time with heroku but I don't remember any tutorial mentions this file. Can you explain a bit about this file and why its important?. Oh and I edited my post. Thank again bud

Comment: There is plenty of information about the `Procfile` online. It's mandatory for a lot of stacks, but with Node.js if there is no `Procfile` Heroku defaults to running the `"start"` script. Do you see the `"build"` script run when you deploy your code? What's in `scripts/build.js`?

Comment: @chris yeah, i see the build running when I deploy. and look, I'm pretty sure there's a problem with heroku and mobx cuz other pages that not using MobX state and only jsx, working perfectly. but when I need to take info from MobX state, the page is total blank and I get that error on the console :\